# How to use SFINAE on three methods with Intel C++ Compiler (ICC)?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, icc

I'm trying to add support for icc on one of my projects, but I have some issues with SFINAE, when there are more than two methods. Here is a bare simple example of the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t Selector>
struct impl {
    template<bool Enable = true, typename std::enable_if<Selector == 1 && Enable, int>::type = 0>
    static void apply(){
        std::cout << "First selector" << std::endl;
    }

    template<bool Enable = true, typename std::enable_if<Selector == 2 && Enable, int>::type = 0>
    static void apply(){
        std::cout << "Second selector" << std::endl;
    }

    template<bool Enable = true, typename std::enable_if<Selector == 3 && Enable, int>::type = 0>
    static void apply(){
        std::cout << "Big selector" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    impl<1>::apply();
    impl<2>::apply();
    impl<3>::apply();

    return 0;
}
```

This works like a charm with g++ and clang++, but fails to compile with icc:

```
test.cpp(16): error: invalid redeclaration of member function template "void impl<Selector>::apply() [with Selector=1UL]" (declared at line 11)
      static void apply(){
                  ^
          detected during instantiation of class "impl<Selector> [with Selector=1UL]" at line 22

test.cpp(11): error: invalid redeclaration of member function template "void impl<Selector>::apply() [with Selector=3UL]" (declared at line 6)
      static void apply(){
                  ^
          detected during instantiation of class "impl<Selector> [with Selector=3UL]" at line 24

compilation aborted for test.cpp (code 2)
```

Is there a workaround for this with icc ? I'd like to avoid changing too much code, I have this problem in several places of my project.

I'm using icc 16.0.2.164.

Thanks

Comment: The obvious workaround would be partial specialization. Even if that means moving `apply` to a `impl_base<Selector>`, and adding `using impl_base<Selector>` to `impl` itself. This entirely sidesteps the need for SFINAE.

Comment: What version of ICC do you use?

Comment: This is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, anyway. For any given instantiation of `impl`, no valid specialization can be generated for at least two out of the three `apply`s.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm using icc 16.0.2.164. 
I simply want to select a function based on one of the type parameters of the parent class. 
@T.C. Could you develop ? 
In my case, there are other template parameters in the class and I have this problem at several places in my project, I'd like to avoid changing too much code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the code shown in the question, explicitly specializing the member function, as shown in @Jarod42's answer, is probably the simplest.

When SFINAE'ing a class template member function based on parameters of the class template, getting the code correct can be tricky. [temp.res]/p8:

> If no valid specialization can be generated for a template, and that
>   template is not instantiated, the template is ill-formed, no
>   diagnostic required.

The trick is to have the SFINAE expression depend on parameters of the member function template:

```
template<std::size_t Selector>
struct impl {
    template<std::size_t S = Selector, typename std::enable_if<S == 1, int>::type = 0>
    static void apply(){
        std::cout << "First selector" << std::endl;
    }

    template<std::size_t S = Selector, typename std::enable_if<S == 2, int>::type = 0>
    static void apply(){
        std::cout << "Second selector" << std::endl;
    }

    template<std::size_t S = Selector, typename std::enable_if<S == 3, int>::type = 0>
    static void apply(){
        std::cout << "Big selector" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Note that each of the above `apply()`s has one valid specialization.

Comment: It works indeed, thanks, but why doesn't it work with simply adding a bool template parameter ? And why does it work with gcc/clang ?

Comment: @BaptisteWicht Because in your code, there is no possible way to generate a valid specialization for, say, the first `apply` in `impl<2>`. Regardless of the value of the bool parameter, the signature remains invalid. Since no diagnostic is required, compilers are allowed, but not required, to reject it.

Answer (score 2):

Specialization is a solution:

```
template<std::size_t Selector>
struct impl {
    static void apply();
};

template<>
void impl<1>::apply(){
    std::cout << "First selector" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void impl<2>::apply(){
    std::cout << "Second selector" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void impl<3>::apply(){
    std::cout << "Big selector" << std::endl;
}
```